# how to attach a static IP address programmatically (Python) in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, static-ip-address, google-vpc

I am trying to programatically(Python) create a virtual machine with a static IP address that I have.
My code is based on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/compute/api/create_instance.py

I am specifically looking at line 74 to 79. Is there a way to **attach** my static IP address like by referencing, say, the name of the static IP address or something? Now I am just literally hardcoding my static IP address into *accessConfigs* on line 77. I feel like there should be a better/proper way to do it.

Again, I am **not** trying to create a VM with a default IP and replace it with a static IP. 
I am trying to create a VM with a static IP address.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the IP into the `natIP` field. You can:

- hardcode this value. That is bad
- Pass the IP value in param of your script
- Perform a request to [get the IP of an existing static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#list_ip), extract the IP value and pass it to the script